# NSTextView freezing my app when adding a lot of data asyncronously

Tags: asynchronous, swift3, nstextview, osc

I'm building a simple talker/listener app that receives OSC data through UDP.  I'm using OSCKit pod which itself uses CocoaAsyncSocket library for the internal UDP communication.
 
When I'm listening to a particular port to receive data from another OSC capable software, I log the received commands to a `NSTextView`.  The problem is that sometimes, I receive thousands of messages in a very short period of time (**EDIT: I just added a counter to see how many messages I'm receiving.  I got over 14000 in just a few seconds and that is only a single moving object in my software**).  There is no way to predict when this is gonna happen so I cannot lock the `textStorage` object of the `NSTextView` to keep it from sending all its notifications to update the UI.  The data is processed through a delegate callback function.
 
So how would you go around that limitation?

```
   ///Handle incoming OSC messages
   func handle(_ message: OSCMessage!) {

      print("OSC Message: \(message)")

      let targetPath = message.address
      let args = message.arguments

      let msgAsString = "Path: \"\(targetPath)\"\nArguments: \n\(args)\n\n"
      print(msgAsString)
      oscLogView.string?.append(msgAsString)
      oscLogView.scrollToEndOfDocument(self)
   }
```

As you can see here (this is the callback function) I'm updating the TextView directly from the callback (both adding data and scrolling to the end), every time a message is received.  This is where Instruments tell me the slow down happens and the append is the slowest one.  I didn't go further than that in the analysis, but it certainly is due to the fact that it tries to do a visual update, which takes a lot more time than parsing 32bits of data, and when it's finished it receives another update right away from the server's buffer.

Could I send that call to the background thread?  I don't feel like filling up the background thread with visual updates is such a great idea.  Maybe growing my own string buffer and flushing it to the TextView every now and then with a timer?

I want to give this a console feel, but a console that freezes is not a console.

Here is a link to the [project on github](https://github.com/sonoblaise/OSC-Toolbox/).  the pods are all there and configured with cocoapods, so just open the workspace.  You guys might not have anything to generate that much OSC traffic, but if you really feel like digging in, you can get IanniX, which is an open-source sequencer/trajectory automator that can generate OSC and a lot of it.  I've just downloaded it and I'll build a quick project that should send enough data to freeze the app and I'll add it to the repo if anybody want to give it a shot.

Comment: Since you have 14000 results and it wouldn't be possibly acceptable in a single scrolling interface, couldn't you like skip the messages that come like, whithin 0.01s or so? So you would block the update every 0.01s and wait for the next message after that, it would result in a maximum of 100 messages per second, which would be fast enough to see and to not slow it all down, I guess.

Comment: No message can be skipped.  I'm just filling a buffer and adding it to the textView with a timer instead.  Works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I append the incoming data to a buffer variable and I use a timer that flushes that buffer to the textview every 0.2 seconds.  The update cycle of the textview is way too slow to handle the amount of incoming data so unloding the network callback to a timer let the server process the data instead of being stopped every 32bits.

If anybody come up with a more elegant method, I'm open minded.

Comment: Hello, Badger. Please edit your question to add further information instead of posting an aswer, it makes the understanding more clear. Thanks.

Comment: I thought that would be fine since it's the solution I found ;). I'll update the question tonight.

Comment: Wops, sorry about that. The last line confused me, but it's ok, you're right

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16838652)

Comment: @Arpit : if you read properly, it it a solution.  Leaving it open for suggestions does not make it a question.  I did not mark the question as answered yet in case I get other solutions.